# Error message "npm ERR! typeerror Error: Missing required argument #2"

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2017

When I try to install or update Node.js packages via *package.json* in Visual Studio 2017 Pro, I get the error message below:

#### Error

```
PATH=.\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Web\External;%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\mingw32\bin
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Web\External\npm.CMD" install
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.17134
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Professional\\Web\\External\\Node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Professional\\Web\\External\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.4.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.4
npm ERR! code EMISSINGARG
npm ERR! typeerror Error: Missing required argument #2
npm ERR! typeerror     at exports.findRequirement (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Web\External\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:475:3)
npm ERR! typeerror     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Web\External\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:90:19
npm ERR! typeerror     at zalgoSafe (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Web\External\node_modules\dezalgo\dezalgo.js:20:10)
npm ERR! typeerror     at finalize (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Web\External\node_modules\realize-package-specifier\index.js:37:5)
npm ERR! typeerror     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Web\External\node_modules\realize-package-specifier\index.js:22:20
npm ERR! typeerror     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR! typeerror     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Morten\Documents\GitHub\MyProject\src\MyProject\MyProject.Web\npm-debug.log
```

#### File *npm-debug.log*

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Professional\\Web\\External\\Node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Professional\\Web\\External\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install' ]
2 info using npm@3.3.4
3 info using node@v5.4.1
4 silly loadCurrentTree Starting
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 silly install normalizeTree
8 verbose stack Error: Missing required argument #2
8 verbose stack     at exports.findRequirement (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Web\External\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:475:3)
8 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Web\External\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:90:19
8 verbose stack     at zalgoSafe (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Web\External\node_modules\dezalgo\dezalgo.js:20:10)
8 verbose stack     at finalize (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Web\External\node_modules\realize-package-specifier\index.js:37:5)
8 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Web\External\node_modules\realize-package-specifier\index.js:22:20
8 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
9 verbose cwd C:\Users\Morten\Documents\GitHub\MyProject\src\MyProject\MyProject.Web
10 error Windows_NT 10.0.17134
11 error argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Professional\\Web\\External\\Node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Professional\\Web\\External\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
12 error node v5.4.1
13 error npm  v3.3.4
14 error code EMISSINGARG
15 error typeerror Error: Missing required argument #2
15 error typeerror     at exports.findRequirement (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Web\External\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:475:3)
15 error typeerror     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Web\External\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:90:19
15 error typeerror     at zalgoSafe (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Web\External\node_modules\dezalgo\dezalgo.js:20:10)
15 error typeerror     at finalize (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Web\External\node_modules\realize-package-specifier\index.js:37:5)
15 error typeerror     at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Web\External\node_modules\realize-package-specifier\index.js:22:20
15 error typeerror     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
15 error typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
15 error typeerror     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
16 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turned out that having a comment in my package.json file caused the problem. After removing the comment (see below), packages update and install again.

**I had this:**

```
"devDependencies": {
  "gulp": "3.9.1",
  "//": "Gulp-sass 4 requires Node 6 or greater, https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass/issues/684",
  "gulp-sass": "3.2.1",
  "gulp-cssmin": "0.2.0",
  "gulp-concat": "2.6.1",
  ...
```

**I changed to this**

```
"devDependencies": {
  "gulp": "3.9.1",
  "gulp-sass": "3.2.1",
  "gulp-cssmin": "0.2.0",
  "gulp-concat": "2.6.1",
  ...
```

Also see: GitHub issue *[Error with npm itself #19868](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19868)*

Answer (score 5):

It's due to the obsolete Node.js and npm versions.

Update your node version and npm version with the following commands in Ubuntu/Debian systems.

```
# Using Ubuntu
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -

sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

# Using Debian, as root
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -

apt-get install -y nodejs
```

For other operating systems, please refer to [Node.js installation/upgrade](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debinstall).

Comment: What if one cannot run that as root?

Answer (score 0):

`gulp-saas` is supported by npm 4 and above.

Updating the version of NPM using `npm install npm@latest` will solve the problem.

Comment: This would be the best since it does not require sudo. Sadly it failes with similar error